# How to access remote database from laravel 4.2

Tags: database, laravel

I am currently do some development in a early developed system developed from laravel 4.2.
I run it in my local machine. At the same time now I have to access to a another System's database.
For testing purposes i have created that db in my local server. I don't have direct access to that db in real situation. Only i have a view. So please tell me how should i configure my system to achieve that task.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a separate database connection to your other system's database, so in your `app/config/database.php` you can have this:

```
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'forge',
            'username'  => 'forge',
            'password'  => '123456',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'forge2',
            'username'  => 'forge2',
            'password'  => '123456',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

In order to perform query to the other database you have to do this:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
```

You may see this code in the Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections